# How to fix CS1701 error for system.runtime in Powertshell embed C#

Tags: c#, powershell

The Powershell function below generates numerous errors when compiling the C# part.

```
    function New-ClientWebSocketEventBridge {
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Websocket.Client.WebsocketClient] $ws
    )
    # is this type already defined?
    if (-not ("ClientWebSocketEventBridge" -as [type])) {
        $cp = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime;
using Websocket.Client;
using Websocket.Client.Models;

public sealed class ClientWebSocketEventBridge {
    
    public Event EventHandler<ReconnectionInfo> Connection;
    
    public WebsocketClient wsConnection;
    public string Name;
    
    private ClientWebSocketEventBridge( WebsocketClient ws ) {
        wsConnection = ws;
        if (ws.Name != null) { Name = ws.Name; }
        ws.ReconnectionHappened.Subscribe(info => Connection?.Invoke(this, info));
    }
    
    public static ClientWebSocketEventBridge Create( WebsocketClient ws )
    {
        return new ClientWebSocketEventBridge( ws );
    }
}
"@
        Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cp -ReferencedAssemblies 'Websocket.Client'
    }
    $bridge = [ClientWebSocketEventBridge]::Create( $ws )
    return $bridge
}
```

I suspect that most of the other errors are the consequence of the error concerning a version problem in the System.Runtime assembly.

```
    Add-Type:
Line |
  34 |          Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cp -ReferencedAssemblies 'Websocket …
     |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | error CS1701: En supposant que la référence d'assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' utilisée par 'Websocket.Client' correspond à l'identité 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' de 'System.Runtime', il se peut que vous deviez fournir une stratégie runtime
```

I understand that the Websocket.Client assembly uses/requires System.Runtime Version=6.0.0.0 while Powershell uses/requires Version=7.0.0.0.

How can I correct this problem?

Comment: Is this assuming you have downloaded the net6 version of this assembly and you're using PowerShell 7.3+ ?

Comment: yes, the net7 version of the assembly does not exist.

Comment: After instal of visual studio I successfully built the net7 version of assembly. Then, no more problem. However it may be useful to know the way to solve such problem in case source is not available ...